# Power Rule for Complex Logarithms

Tags: logarithms

Given $z \in \mathbb{C}$, could you explain to me why:
$$
\log(z^n) \neq n\log(z)
$$
in terms of analytic branches of $\log$ functions?

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the principal branch of the logarithm, namely
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Log} z= \log|z|+i\arg z \ \ \text{ where } -\pi<\arg z<\pi
\end{align}
for all $z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{(-\infty, 0]\}$.

Clearly, we see that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Log} (-1)^2 =\operatorname{Log} 1= \log 1 + i\arg 1 = 0
\end{align}
but $2\operatorname{Log}(-1)$ doesn't make sense.

**Additional Example**: Let $z = i$, then $z^4 = 1$. Next, observe
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Log} 1 = 0 \neq 4\operatorname{Log} i = 4\left( \log|i|+i\arg i\right) = 4i\frac{\pi}{2} = 2\pi i. 
\end{align}

Comment: Why did you exclude the set $(-\infty,0]$?

Comment: @ASlowLearner have you learn what a branch of the logarithm is?

Comment: A branch of a log function is an interval of angle within which the log function is single-valued, isn't it? In your answer, shouldn't the principal branch of log is $(-\pi,\pi]$ instead of $(-\pi,\pi)$?

Comment: @A Slow Learner Most authors exclude the negative real axis altogether to deal with an open set.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{\ln\pars{z} = \ln\pars{\verts{z}} + \arg\pars{z}\ic\,,\quad
> z \not= 0\,,\quad -\pi < \arg\pars{z} < \pi;\quad}$ see this *example*:

\begin{align}
\ln\pars{-1 + \ic} + \ln\pars{-1 + \ic} & =
\bracks{{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{2} + {3\pi \over 4}\,\ic} +
\bracks{{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{2} + {3\pi \over 4}\,\ic} = \ln\pars{2} +
\color{red}{{3\pi \over 2}\,\ic}
\\[5mm]
\ln\pars{\bracks{-1 + \ic}\bracks{-1 + \ic}} & = \ln\pars{-2\ic} =
\ln\pars{2} \color{red}{- {\pi \over 2}\,\ic}
\\[5mm]
\implies & \bbx{\ln\pars{\bracks{-1 + \ic}\bracks{-1 + \ic}} \not=
\ln\pars{-1 + \ic} + \ln\pars{-1 + \ic}}
\end{align}